# JBOSS | Jasper report error

Tags: jboss, jasper-reports

My application generates some reports to it's clients. But there's an error when generating the reports here's the exception:-

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.NameEnvironmentAnswer.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/env/IBinaryType;)V
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler$1.findType(JRJdtCompiler.java:235)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler$1.findType(JRJdtCompiler.java:204)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:119)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getType(PackageBinding.java:126)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findType(Scope.java:1355)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2472)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2194)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:39)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:141)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:104)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1107)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:767)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:947)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:266)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:195)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:301)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:315)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler.compileClass(JRJdtCompiler.java:392)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler.compileReport(JRJdtCompiler.java:109)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDefaultCompiler.compileReport(JRDefaultCompiler.java:106)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:128)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:110)
```

Recently I moved this application to **JBOSS 4.0.5.GA**. This application was running fine and there's no errors in generating reports in **Tomcat 5**

Thanks.

Comment: You might also find the Report Integration Framework to be useful. http://www.whitemagicsoftware.com/software/java/rif/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a conflicting JAR file:

```
jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar
```

I created a script to set the CLASSPATH before Tomcat runs:

```
#!/bin/bash

IREPORT_HOME=$HOME/bin/ireport
CLASSPATH=$IREPORT_HOME/platform9/modules/org-netbeans-core.jar:

for j in \
  $IREPORT_HOME/ireport/modules/ext/*.jar \
  $IREPORT_HOME/ide10/modules/ext/*.jar; do
  BASENAME=$(basename $j)

  # Append file names to the CLASSPATH, except those with Tomcat conflicts.
  if [ "$BASENAME" != "jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar" ]; then
    CLASSPATH=$j:$CLASSPATH
  fi
done

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH.
```

Save it as `setenv.sh` and place it in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin`. You will have to change the `IREPORT_HOME` variable accordingly.